# Form Validation in Disabled JavaScript

Tags: javascript, forms

Is there any way to perform *client side form validation* when JavasSript is disabled in browser?

Comment: no there is not. only server side.

Comment: Without use of plug-ins or the new HTML5 input types (eg `<input type="email" />`), no.

Comment: check this link may help you 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2056448/is-it-possible-to-have-client-side-validation-without-javascript

Comment: You should **never ever** rely on client side validation.

Comment: May be using server side validation when javascript is disabled will fit your requirements.

Comment: I don't. Client side- Server side - Database Data Integrity constraints. right!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

HTML 5 introduces some [validation features](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#client-side-form-validation) (limited browser support), but other than that — no.

However, you shouldn't worry too much about it since:

- most users will have JS supporting browsers with JS enabled
- you need to have have server side validation in place (since client side validation can save users from making mistakes, but it can't prevent malicious attacks) and if JS isn't available, then it will simply fall back to the server and you get the same result with just an extra HTTP request added.

Answer (score 1):

There's HTML5 form validation, and AFAIK Opera supports it even if client-scripting is disabled. See:

http://www.the-art-of-web.com/html/html5-form-validation/

[Do any browsers yet support HTML5's checkValidity() method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2421218/do-any-browsers-yet-support-html5s-checkvalidity-method)