# I need to validate my form without using JavaScript

Tags: php, javascript, html, internet-explorer

How can I validate my form without using JavaScript? I have used the required HTML 5 attribute   but as IE doesn't support IE (ANNOYING) is there a way around this with using PHP which will take time.

Thanks

Comment: I assume you know how to do server-side validation, right?

Comment: -1. Go Google "form validation in php"... + even when validating client side you should ALWAYS validate server side too.

Comment: Also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2056448/is-it-possible-to-have-client-side-validation-without-javascript -- I know you say no JS, but could you use something like [WebShims](http://afarkas.github.com/webshim/demos/)? That way JS would only run where the attribute is unsupported.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should *always* validate on the server side (e.g., with PHP).  There are probably a lot of libraries that will make this easier and save you some time, but the principle's pretty simple:

```
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
   $name = isset($_POST['name']) ? $_POST['name'] : null;
}
$errors = '';
if (!$name or strlen($name) < 5) {
   $errors .= 'Name must not be empty and at least five characters';
}
if ($errors) {
   echo $errors;
}
else {
   //Store data from the form or whatever you want to do.
}
```

I would also recommend using Post/Redirect/Get

Answer (score 0):

You can use PHP to validate using the server:

http://thinkvitamin.com/code/php-form-validation/

Answer (score 0):

Only server side validation (ie in PHP) or using javascript. Although, I'd go for the server side part - it is the safest, since a bad user could forge bad data from the client side